# makefile for arm port of linux uCOS-II - can't understand the error I'm getting

Tags: linux, assembly, makefile, arm

I was able to compile the Linux port of uCOS-II for an i386 Linux machine. Now there's a ARM port which has an s assembly file. I was able to find out what I believe are the appropriate assembler flags like: -mcpu=arm920t -mapcs-32. I've been able to cobble together this [makefile](http://www.hampleman.com/upload/Makefile.txt) (the port didn't come with a makefile) which can create the object files but I'm not sure how to link them together using make. Do I need a linker script? [Here's](http://www.hampleman.com/upload/ucosa.zip) the project I'm using. The make file is run from the linux-test subdirectory. The s file is linux-test/os_cpu_a.s and the error is:
ucosasm.o(.text+0x3d0): In function 'OS_CPU_SR_FIQ_En: undefined ref to OS_CPU_ExceptHndlr

which is weird because in OS_CPU_SR_FIQ_En there is no ref to OS_CPU_ExceptHndlr.

All of the object files get created but the $(CC) -o ... line at the end of the makefile is what I think links them all together is when the error occurs.

There is a listing.txt which is the listing of the s file when its assembled. I'm really not up on my ARM assembly. Hope someone can help.

Comment: The error location is misleading, but the symbol is indeed undefined, at least I couldn't find it anywhere in the whole archive.  Can you point out where you think it is defined? Maybe you are expected to provide an implementation for it?

Comment: You're right. I'll have to do some further investigation.

Comment: I was able to supress the error by adding an empty function OS_CPU_ExceptHndlr() to main.c but now it creates a binary file called '-I.' so there's something wrong with my Makefile.

Comment: `$(CC) -o $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(BUILD_TARGET)-main ...` is wrong of course. You want something more like `$(CC) -o  $(BUILD_TARGET)-main $(INCLUDE_PATHS) ...` *Although on second thought not sure why you even need include path for linking.

Comment: OK I got the makefile to work and can run it on my target board but after the tasks start it stops at the first OSTimeDly()

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing calling OSTimeTick(). I guess the solution is to use iTimer/Signal?